# Escaping bracket in database name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to create database in an application with a name provided runtime.

The current solution is:

`create database [USER_PROVIDED_NAME] ...`

The problem is with that solution is that the user provided name can contain [ or ] leading to syntax error (and possibly SQL injection).

Is there a way to do it safely, without limiting the possible database names?

Comment: Escape the right bracket: `CREATE DATABASE [This is a [really]] bad idea for a [database]] name];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
select quotename('foo[bar]baz'); -- [foo[bar]]baz]
create database [foo[bar]]baz];
```

That being said, I would rather reject such names using a whitelist of allowed characters.

Comment: *"I would rather reject such names using a whitelist of allowed characters."* 100% this.

Answer (score 1):

If this is controlled in your application, then you can delimit identify and escape the right brackets (`]`). The left brackets (`[`) don't need escaping:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [This is a [really]] bad idea for a [database]] name];
```

Alternatively, if you want to handle this in the SQL layer and the database name is coming from the application, you could use dynamic SQL and `QUOTENAME`:

```sql
DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname = N'This is a [really] bad idea for a [database] name'; --This is your parameter

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N';';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ANSI escaping double quotes here:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE "Name with [stuff]";
```

Comment: What about if the user wants to include double quotes in the name? :)

Comment: Not sure I follow your comment.  If we can't use square brackets to escape the DB name, and use double quotes instead, then why it matter where/if we put square brackets into the database name?

Comment: My point is that i suspect that the OP is saying that the name could contain *any* character. So if you use double quotes (`"`) to delimit identify, what happens if the user wants to create a database called `This is Steve "The Power" Smith's Database`?

Comment: @Larnu ... then we can escape double quotes by doubling them up.  We can't run forever.